# ASP.NET MVC App Redirects Break in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc, debugging, azure-web-apps

**Info**

I'm developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC.  It works great running locally (or even on a test server on my network).  The moment I push it up to Azure, a couple of the redirects break giving a generic 500 error.  I can't imagine what the trouble is.  I've even done explicit paths for all the affected redirects and it still manages to break.  I would love to hear if someone can tell me how to go about solving this.

**Code:**

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteOption(int id)
{
    Option o = Option.GetOptionByID(cadb, id);
    long qid = o.QuestionID;
    Option.Delete(cadb, id);
    return Redirect("/Build/ManageOptions?id=" + qid);
}
```

View:  the button that invokes the controller method

```
<a href="/Build/DeleteOption?id=@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
```

I don't think the Model has any bearing here, but if for some reason you would like to see it, let me know.

If any info is missing please ask and I'll happily add it ASAP.  Thanks!